# React contenteditable cursor jumps to beginning

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable

I am using the module [react-simple-contenteditable](https://github.com/raphasilvac/react-simple-contenteditable) to enable editing of a fill in the blank worksheet. The reason I must use a content editable element instead of an input element is because I want the text of the problem to wrap. For example, if a problem has one blank, it divides the text into three sections the part before the blank, the blank, and the part after. If I were to represent the outer two as separate `div`s (or input fields), then the text would not wrap like a paragraph. Instead, I must have a single contenteditable  `div` that contains an input field for the blank and free text on either side.

The text is wrapping like I want it, but when I type text in the contenteditable field, the cursor jumps to the beginning. I don't understand why because I tried the example on the [module's github site](https://github.com/raphasilvac/react-simple-contenteditable) and it works perfectly, and although my implementation is a bit more complicated, it works essentially the same.

Here is my render function that uses `<ContentEditable />` :

```
render() {
    const textPieces =
      <div className='new-form-text-pieces'>
        {
          this.props.problem.textPieces.map( (textPiece, idx) => {
            if (textPiece.blank) {
              return (
                  <div data-blank={true} className='blank' key={ textPiece.id } style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Answer blank"
                      className='new-form-answer-input'
                      value={ this.props.problem.textPieces[idx].text }
                      onChange={ (event) => this.props.handleTextPiecesInput(this.props.problemIdx, idx, event.target.value) }
                    />
                    <button className='modify-blank remove-blank' onClick={ (event) => this.props.removeBlank(this.props.problemIdx, idx) }>-</button>

                  </div>
              );
            } else {
              let text = this.props.problem.textPieces[idx].text;
              const placeholder = idx === 0 ? 'Problem text' : '...continue text';
              // text = text === '' ? placeholder : text;
              if (text === '') {
                text = <span style={{color:'gray'}}>{placeholder}</span>;
              } else {

              }
              return (
                this.props.isTextSplit ?
                  <TextPiece
                    key={ textPiece.id }
                    problemIdx={this.props.problemIdx}
                    textPieceIdx={idx}
                    dropBlank={this.props.dropBlank}
                    moveBlank={this.props.moveBlank}
                  >
                    <div style={{display: 'inline-block', }}>{text}</div>
                  </TextPiece>
                : text

              );
            }
          })
        }
      </div>;



    return (
       this.props.isTextSplit ? textPieces :
        <ContentEditable
          html={ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(textPieces)}
          className="my-class"
          tagName="div"
          onChange={ (event, value) => this.props.handleProblemChange(event, this.props.problemIdx, value) }
          contentEditable='plaintext-only'
        />
    );

  }
```

Here is the `onChange` function:

```
handleProblemChange(event, problemIdx) {
    const problems = cloneDeep(this.state.problems);
    event.target.children[0].childNodes.forEach( (textPieceNode, idx) => {
      if (textPieceNode.constructor === Text) {
        problems[problemIdx].textPieces[idx].text = textPieceNode.wholeText;
      } else {
        problems[problemIdx].textPieces[idx].text = textPieceNode.childNodes[0].value;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ problems });
  }
```

And here is the state it refers to, just to make thing clear:

```
this.state = {
  problems: [
    {
      id: shortid.generate(),
      textPieces: [
        {
          text : "Three days was simply not a(n)",
          blank : false,
          id: shortid.generate(),
        },
        {
          text : "acceptable",
          blank : true,
          id: shortid.generate(),
        },
        {
          text : "amount of time to complete such a lot of work.",
          blank : false,
          id: shortid.generate(),
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, there is no easy way to do this. I have tried this myself and spent days trying. Basically you have to save the cursor position and reposition it yourself after the update. All of this can be achieved with window.getSelection()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

But it can get really tricky depending on how much your content has changed.

I ended up using draftJS instead. Which is an abstraction over contenteditable div by facebook themselves.

https://draftjs.org/docs/overview.html#content

A bit longer to pick up but you will be able to do a lot more

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll take another look at DraftJS, it looked pretty complicated. Can it be implemented for just simple fields like for what I'm doing or is it just for rich text edits like it's advertised for?

Comment: It can do both. Although not simple, I would bet on it being simpler than managing the cursor state yourself.

Comment: Coming back to this now... I scanned through the docs of DraftJS and I can't find the answer to another question, so I thought maybe you might know: can I make the inner content html elements? In addition to the content editable text, I need text with a box around it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using **VueJS**.

Here is the component containing the contenteditable div :

```html
<Text @update-content="updateContent" :current-item-content="item.html_content"/>
```

Here is the prop definition in Text.vue component :

```js
const props = defineProps({
    currentItemContent: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
})
```

Here is the contenteditable div in Text.vue component :

```html
<div
    id="text-editor"
    ref="text_editor"
    class="mt-3 h-full w-full break-words"
    contenteditable="true"
    @input="updateContent"
    v-html="currentItemContent"
>
```

Here is the method triggered on @update-content event

```js
const item = computed(() => { ... })
(...)
function updateContent(content) {
    item.value.html_content = content
}
```

The problem here is injecting the `item.html_content` value as a props triggers a re-render of the contenteditable div.
Because it's mutating it's value in the updateContent method and as the computed (`item`) is beeing updated, so does the prop value, `v-html` detects the updated value and triggers a re-render.

To avoid this, i removed the v-html binding :

```html
<div
    id="text-editor"
    ref="text_editor"
    class="mt-3 h-full w-full break-words"
    contenteditable="true"
    @input="updateContent"
>
```

And initialized the value of the contenteditable div in a onMounted hook :

```js
const text_editor = ref(null)
(...)
onMounted(() => {
    if (props.currentItemContent !== '') {
        text_editor.value.innerHTML = props.currentItemContent 
    }
})
```

I don't know if there is a better solution for this but it's working fine for me. Hope this helps someone

Comment: This is the approach that worked for me. It is better to do it this way because we can decide when to update the element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my case I just added a

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in the "onInput" props, I think the cause is the react refresh

Answer (score 0):

I know they work differently but in my case, simply using `onBlur` in place of `onInput` worked. I hope it helps.