# React using a hook with contentEditable updates, but re-focuses curser every key stroke

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, contenteditable

I have tried a dozen different approaches to this ..  And I am super close.  This is the code I have:

```
function Dashboard() {

   const [html, setHTML] = useState("");

   return (
      <pre
          contentEditable="true"
          onKeyUp={e => setHTML(e.currentTarget.textContent)}
      >
          {html}
      </pre>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

It "works" although it refocuses the cursor back to the top of the `<pre>` tag every key stroke.  I have used `onKeyDown` -- `onChange` etc etc with the same result -- The cursor always refocuses and sets to the start of the `<pre>` tag.

So this is a two part question.  I am assuming this has something to do with React and the way it treats hooks and renders.  With that said:

1. Why does this happen, and is it a "feature"?
2. Given what I am trying to accomplish, how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Not directly related to your questions but it's generally not recommended to use `contentEditable`. Unless there's a very good reason to use `pre` and `contentEditable`, consider using `textarea`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React contenteditable cursor jumps to beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257519/react-contenteditable-cursor-jumps-to-beginning)

Comment: @technophyle the reason for using `contentEditable` is that I am editing HTML .. Which React treats as an Object inside a `textarea`

Comment: @technophyle and the post you gave was way more complicated than it needed to be, so it was unhelpful in this case.  See my answer below ... This will help anyone wanting to make a BASIC html editor without needing to install a Rich Text Editor or a third party library.  It would be easier if React treated a textarea as raw text, but it treats raw HTML as React components, even though they are inside a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK .. The reason this is happening is that I am calling `{html}` inside the `<pre>` tag.  So every time the state changes:

```
onKeyUp={e => setHTML(e.currentTarget.textContent)}
```

it re-renders the `{html}` inside the `<pre>` -- Thus resetting the cursor to the top.  So that's the answer to question 1 -- Why was this happening?

To answer question 2 --> To circumvent this, you need two separated hooks:

```
const [initialHtml, setInitialHTML] = useState("<div>Original HTML</div>");
const [newHtml, setNewHTML] = useState("");
```

Then you can now set your `newHTML` while not re-rendering the `initialHtml`

```
<pre
    contentEditable="true"
    onInput={e => setNewHTML(e.currentTarget.innerText)}
>
    {InitialHtml}
</pre>
```

**NOTE:** I also changed `onKeyUp` to `onInput` to account for "paste" actions via the mouse or other methods.  I also changed `textContent` to `innerText` as to preserve whitspace and line breaks.