# Fill an input field with a value of a link and set the cursor to the beginning of the inputfield

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with the following:

I have 2 react components:

InputSetter.jsx
It shows an input field with a value that is derived from a link. It sets the cursor to the start of the inputfield.

StringList.jsx
Shows a list of strings with an onClick event to pass the string in that link to the InputSetter component.

- test1
- test2
- test3

App.jsx to tie every together.

This is what it should do:
1 - Show a list of links
2 - When I click on a link, the word in that link should be shown in an input field in the InputSetter component.
3 - The cursor in the input field should be placed before that word.
4 - As soon as I start entering text in the input field before that word, the cursor should behave normally. It should follow the characters that I type.

So far, point 1, 2 and 3 work. But when I start typing, the cursor is set to the start of the input field for every character I type. As a result, the string that I type is shown in reverse.

So, when I click on the link test1 and enter "hello" it becomes "ollehtest1".

I don't have much experience in react, so please be patient.

This is the code sofar:

```
// StringList.jsx
import React from 'react';

const StringList = ({ handleLinkClick }) => {
  // Words for the links
  const linkWords = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Links */}
      {linkWords.map((word, index) => (
        <a
          key={index}
          className="block text-blue-500 cursor-pointer"
          href="#"
          onClick={() => handleLinkClick(word)}
        >
          {word}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StringList;
```

```
// InputSetter.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const InputSetter = ({ inputValue, onInputChange }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set focus and cursor position after mounting
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
    }
  }, []); // Only run this effect once after mounting

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setCursorPosition(event.target.selectionStart);
    // If needed, you can propagate the input change to the parent component
    if (onInputChange) {
      onInputChange(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={inputValue}
        ref={inputRef}
        id="inputField" // Add an id to the input field for easier identification
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default InputSetter;
```

```
// TestTable.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import StringList from './StringList';
import InputSetter from './InputSetter';

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const cursorPositionRef = useRef(0);

  const handleLinkClick = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);

    // Set focus and update the cursor position after updating the input value
    const inputElement = document.getElementById('inputField');
    if (inputElement) {
      // Set the cursor position to the start of the input value after a short delay
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputElement.focus();
        cursorPositionRef.current = 0; // Update the cursor position
        inputElement.setSelectionRange(cursorPositionRef.current, cursorPositionRef.current);
        console.log('Link Click - Cursor Position:', cursorPositionRef.current);
      }, 0);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    cursorPositionRef.current = e.target.selectionStart; // Update the cursor position
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set focus and cursor position after updating the input value
    const inputElement = document.getElementById('inputField');
    if (inputElement) {
      inputElement.focus();
      cursorPositionRef.current = 0; // Update the cursor position
      inputElement.setSelectionRange(cursorPositionRef.current, cursorPositionRef.current);
      console.log('Input Change - Cursor Position:', cursorPositionRef.current);
    }
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <StringList handleLinkClick={handleLinkClick} />
      <InputSetter inputValue={inputValue} onInputChange={handleInputChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to dig through .. But I asked a [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76732140/react-using-a-hook-with-contenteditable-updates-but-re-focuses-curser-every-key) That I ended up answering myself ..  It may help you out.  It is similar in the sense that I needed the cursor to move only ONCE ...  You are in the same boat.  Get the cursor to the beginning, then quit re-rendering using that hook.